# Tomcat Servlet Cookies Example Not Working

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cookies, runtime-error

I am trying to run a cookie example that comes in Tomcat but it is giving me problems. The source code that Tomcat shows for the program is

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class CookieExample extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        // print out cookies

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            Cookie c = cookies[i];
            String name = c.getName();
            String value = c.getValue();
            out.println(name + " = " + value);
        }

        // set a cookie

        String name = request.getParameter("cookieName");
        if (name != null && name.length() > 0) {
            String value = request.getParameter("cookieValue");
            Cookie c = new Cookie(name, value);
            response.addCookie(c);
        }
    }
}
```

And I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at line `for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {`

I am passing the cookieName and cookieValue. I tried setting the cookie first and then printing it but it is giving the same error at the same line. The thing is, when I tried this program few months back, it was working fine on Internet Explorer but not on Chrome. It was giving a http as name and proxy as value I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies()
```

is returning null which is the servlet engine's way of saying zero cookies have been submitted.  You need to guard your for loop with a check against that.

It was likely working 'sometimes' before because at the time there happened to be cookies in your IE session but not chrome that were being sent thereby allowing the loop to execute.